# Ordering by the order of key value

Tags: sql-server

The problem is: I have a table that i want sort items with special id.

For example:

```
Request(Id, Code, Phone, CreatedDate)

1  100  98351265  2014/2/2
2  101  98351269  2014/3/2 
3  102  98351985  2014/5/2 
4  103  98351654  2014/9/2
```

order by `Id=3`

result:

```
3  102  98351985  2014/5/2 
1  100  98351265  2014/2/2
2  101  98351269  2014/3/2 
4  103  98351654  2014/9/2
```

there is away to order by the order of key value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see records with `Id = 3` *first*, and all other records being sorted by `Id` you can put it like that:

```
  select *
    from MyTable
order by case
           when Id = 3 then
             0
           else
             1
         end,    -- <- First, extract records with Id = 3
         Id desc -- <- Next, sort by Id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Can i Order another records with ID Desc?

Answer (score 1):

Could be slow .**UNION** is one solution

```
 SELECT *,1 as rank FROM tbl where id=3
           UNION 
 SELECT *,2 as rank FROM tbl where id!=3 order by rank,id
```

Comment: Sorry, but it won't do: ORDER BY clause sorts the whole query and that's why it doesn't extract records with Id = 3

Comment: Thanks, I use 'Union' but don't show id=3 in first.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
SELECT *
From Table1
Order By CASE When Id = 3 Then 0 Else 1 End Asc,ID Desc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Can i Order another records with ID Desc?